# OpenCL buffer is empty

Tags: c++, kernel, buffer, opencl, gpu

i am trying to learn how to use OpenCL with this tutorial https://anteru.net/blog/2012/11/04/2016/index.html however i don't think the values in the float buffers are being set to anything. and when i read the buffer at the end it is all 0s with a view decimal numbers in scientific notation like it is full of random memory. i'll post the code below. what the kernel does is take in 3 parameters, float buffer x,float buffer y and float a. `const int i = get_global_id(0)` and `y[i] += a * x[i];`
the problem is(i think) that i never put any numbers in aBuffer or bBuffer so the multiplications and addition mean nothing. but a weird thing is that when i make the kernel do this `y[i] += a;` it still gives the same output when i would think it would give 2.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


#ifdef __APPLE__
#include "OpenCL/opencl.h"
#else
#include "CL/cl.h"
#endif


using namespace std;




int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    cl_uint platformIdCount = 0;
    clGetPlatformIDs(0, nullptr, &platformIdCount);

    vector<cl_platform_id> platformIds(platformIdCount);
    clGetPlatformIDs(platformIdCount, platformIds.data(), nullptr);
    cout << "Platforms " << platformIdCount << endl;

    cl_uint deviceIdCount = 0;


    clGetDeviceIDs(platformIds[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 0, nullptr, &deviceIdCount);
    cout << "Devices " << deviceIdCount << endl;

    vector<cl_device_id> deviceIds(deviceIdCount);
    clGetDeviceIDs(platformIds[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, deviceIdCount, deviceIds.data(), nullptr);


    const cl_context_properties contextProperties[] = {

        CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,
        reinterpret_cast<cl_context_properties>(platformIds[0]),
    0,0
};
    cl_int error = 0;
    cl_context context = clCreateContext(contextProperties, deviceIdCount, deviceIds.data(), nullptr, nullptr, &error);

    error = 0;

    cl_mem aBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(float) * (64), nullptr, &error);
    cl_mem bBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(float) * (64), nullptr, &error);



    cl_program program;

    clBuildProgram(program, deviceIdCount, deviceIds.data(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

    cl_kernel kernel1 = clCreateKernel(program, "SAXPY", &error);

    clSetKernelArg(kernel1, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), aBuffer);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel1, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), bBuffer);
    static const float two = 2.0f;
    clSetKernelArg(kernel1, 2, sizeof(float),&two);

    const size_t globalWorkSize [] = {64,0,0};
    cl_command_queue queue;
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel1, 1, nullptr, globalWorkSize, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);



    float done[64];
    clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, bBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float)*64, done, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
    for (int a = 0; a < 64; a++) {
        cout << done[a] << endl;
    }




    clReleaseContext(context);
    return 0;
}
```

.cl file:

```
kernel void SAXPY(__global float* x,__global float* y, float a){
    const int i = get_global_id(0);
    //y[i] = 2.0f;
    y[i] += a * x[i];
}
```

Comment: Try calling `clFinish(queue);` after `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel1, 1, nullptr, globalWorkSize, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);`.

Comment: what does that do?

Comment: It blocks the current CPU thread and waits until all the commands in the `queue` has been processed by the OpenCL device (i.e. GPU). It's possible that your `kernel1` haven't completed the computation when you tried reading the buffer's values.

Comment: i did have a setting to do that here `clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, bBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float)*64, done, 0, nullptr, nullptr);` i believe the CL_TRUE means wait for it to finish before reading it,but i'll try it.     i just tried it and i got the same thing

Comment: i found numerous things wrong when i found some source code, and would still like some help learning this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, when setting kernel argument, you must [pass pointer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clSetKernelArg.html) to the memory object:

```
clSetKernelArg(kernel1, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &aBuffer); // &aBuffer, not aBuffer
clSetKernelArg(kernel1, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &bBuffer); // &bBuffer, not bBuffer
```

Secondly, you didn't [create command queue](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateCommandQueue.html):

```
cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, deviceIds[0], 0, nullptr);
```

Thirdly, you didn't call `clCreateProgramWithSource()` prior to `clBuildProgram()`.

Moreover, try to initialize the `cl_mem` objects:

```
cl_float* mem = (cl_float*) malloc(sizeof(cl_float)*64);
for(int i=0; i<64; i++)
    mem[i] = i;

cl_mem aBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_float) * (64), mem, &error);
cl_mem bBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_float) * (64), mem, &error);

free(mem);
```

Fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/cl.h>
#else
#include "CL/cl.h"
#endif

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    cl_uint platformIdCount = 0;
    clGetPlatformIDs(0, nullptr, &platformIdCount);

    vector<cl_platform_id> platformIds(platformIdCount);
    clGetPlatformIDs(platformIdCount, platformIds.data(), nullptr);

    cl_uint deviceIdCount = 0;
    clGetDeviceIDs(platformIds[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 0, nullptr, &deviceIdCount);

    vector<cl_device_id> deviceIds(deviceIdCount);
    clGetDeviceIDs(platformIds[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, deviceIdCount, deviceIds.data(), nullptr);

    const cl_context_properties contextProperties[] = {

        CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,
        (cl_context_properties)platformIds[0],
        0
    };

    cl_int error = 0;
    cl_context context = clCreateContext(contextProperties, 1, &deviceIds[0], [](const char* errinfo, const void* private_info, size_t cb, void* user_data) -> void {
        /* context-creation and runtime error handler */
        cout << "Context error: " << errinfo << endl;
    }, nullptr, &error);


    cl_float* mem = (cl_float*) malloc(sizeof(cl_float)*64);
    for(int i=0; i<64; i++)
        mem[i] = i;

    cl_mem aBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_float) * (64), mem, &error);
    cl_mem bBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_float) * (64), mem, &error);

    free(mem);

    cl_program program;
    string src = "__kernel void SAXPY(__global float* x, __global float* y, float a){"
                    "size_t i=get_global_id(0);"
                    "y[i]=a*x[i];"
                 "}";

    const char* sources[] = {src.c_str()};
    const size_t lens[] = {src.length()};

    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, sources, lens, &error);
    clBuildProgram(program, 1, &deviceIds[0], nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

    cl_kernel kernel1 = clCreateKernel(program, "SAXPY", &error);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel1, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &aBuffer);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel1, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &bBuffer);
    static const float two = 2.0f;
    clSetKernelArg(kernel1, 2, sizeof(float),&two);

    const size_t globalWorkSize [] = {64,0,0};
    cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, deviceIds[0], 0, nullptr);

    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel1, 1, nullptr, globalWorkSize, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);

    float done[64];
    clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, bBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float)*64, done, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
    for (int a = 0; a < 64; a++)
        cout << done[a] << endl;

    clReleaseContext(context);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i noticed some of those things and that i missed a bunch of functions. Now that i found the source code i will copy that into another project and play with it a bit

Comment: I have another queston. Sarasvati just typed in the kernel functipn but i think you can actually read from a file using this.   ifstream infile { "file.txt" };
string file_contents { istreambuf_iterator<char>(infile), istreambuf_iterator<char>() }; Why does string take parameters. I didnt know strings did this. And why are the two parameters almost identical, what are they?

Comment: Ok i might understand it, tell me if im wrong. So the last parameters is pointing to the end of the file like a null terminator or something. And the first parameter means take chars from infile and put them into file_contents until the char equals the null terminator like thing.

Comment: @BenBeazley you're basically right. The string constructor which takes 2 iterator parameters is described in the [C++ documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) ("(7) range constructor"). Your question regarding this subject [has already been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27407136/5666810), please take a look at it.

Comment: Use `calloc` rather than `malloc` to get already cleared memory.

Comment: Ok i have pne problem and i dont uave time to fix it because im going camping for a few days and im leavig within the hour. I fixed e problems and when i run it i just get from 0 to 63 in done buffer. (I set both abuffer and bbuffer to 0 through 63) the math is not being performed on the buffers. If nobody finds a reason why by the time i get back its probably because i made a mistake typing in the mistakes and will probably find it myself